# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to migrate from `.NET CORE 3` Web API to `.NET CORE 7` Web API, here is my `program.cs` code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
// Add services to the container.

// builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseConnectionString"));
builder.Services.AddCustomizedMvc();
builder.Services.AddCustomAutoMapper();

builder.Services.AddDbContext();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
   option.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
       p.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
   )
);



builder.Services.AddCustomAuthentication();
builder.Services.AddCustomAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCustomIdentity();
builder.Services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);


builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
            {
                // set MaxRequestBodySize property to 200 MB
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200;
            });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = AppSettings.Instance.SwaggerRoutePrefix;
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/doc/swagger.json", "doc");
            });


    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
EmailTemplates.Initialize(app.Environment);


Estato.Core.ServiceProvider.Services = app.Services;

var tempOptions = new RewriteOptions();
tempOptions.AddRedirectToWww();
app.UseRewriter(tempOptions);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Storage")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Storage")
});
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseMvc();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{

    
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120); // Increase the timeout if angular app is taking longer to startup
                                                                //spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200"); // Use this instead to use the angular cli server
    }

});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

and here is ServiceCollectionExtensions code:

```
 namespace Estato.Core.Extensions
 {
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH";
        private static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var jwtAppSettingOptions = AppSettings.Instance.JwtIssuerOptions;
            if (jwtAppSettingOptions == null)
            {
                // Handle the scenario where JwtIssuerOptions is null
                // For example, you could log an error or throw an exception.
                throw new Exception("JwtIssuerOptions is null. Check the configuration.");
            }
            services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions.Issuer;
                options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions.Audience;
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            });

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions.Issuer,

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions.Audience,

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
            {
                configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions.Issuer;
                configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
            });

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                #region  User
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageUsers, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.USER_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageRoles, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.ROLE_CRUD));
                #endregion

                #region Manual
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageAppliancies, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.APPLIANCE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageArchitecturalStyles, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.ARCHITECTURAL_STYLE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBasements, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BASEMENT_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildActions, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_ACTION_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildTechnologies, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_TECHNOLOGY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildTypeGroups, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_TYPE_GROUP_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageCities, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.CITY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageClientTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.CLIENT_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageCoolingTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.COOLING_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageCountries, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.COUNTRY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageDimensions, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.DIMENSION_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageDistricts, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.DISTRICT_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageExteriors, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.EXTERIOR_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageFloorCoverings, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.FLOOR_COVERING_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageHeatingFuels, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.HEATING_FUEL_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageHeatingTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.HEATING_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageIndoorFeatures, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.INDOOR_FEATURE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageMetroKeys, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.METRO_KEY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageMoneyTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.MONEY_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageOutdoorAmenities, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.OUTDOOR_AMENITY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageOwnerTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.OWNER_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageParkings, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.PARKING_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageRegions, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.REGION_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageRoofTypes, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.ROOF_TYPE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageRooms, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.ROOM_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageSizeNames, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.SIZE_NAME_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageViews, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.VIEW_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageZones, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.ZONE_CRUD));
                #endregion

                #region Common
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildAllRoom, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_ALL_ROOM_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildFeatures, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_FEATURE_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildings, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILDING_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildMedia, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_MEDIA_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildPhoto, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_PHOTO_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageBuildZoneAll, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.BUILD_ZONE_ALL_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageCheckingAccount, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.CHECKING_ACCOUNT_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageLocation, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.LOCATION_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageNeighborhood, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.NEIGHBORHOOD_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManageOpenDay, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.OPEN_DAY_CRUD));
                options.AddPolicy(Policies.ManagePhoneNode, policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Permission, Permissions.PHONE_NODE_CRUD));
                #endregion
            });


            return services;
        }



        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomIdentity(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(o =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            });

            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                       .UseSqlServer(AppSettings.Instance.DatabaseConnectionString)
                       .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

            // services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            //     options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            //            .UseNpgsql(AppSettings.Instance.DatabaseConnectionString, o => o.UseNetTopologySuite())
            //            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceProvider ConfigureAutofac(this IServiceCollection services, Autofac.IContainer container)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
            builder.Populate(services);
            container = builder.Build();

            return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomizedMvc(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddControllersAsServices()
                    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                       
                    });

            return services;
        }


    }
}
```

here is error :

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not
> able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: Estato.Controllers.AuthController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.AuthController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.Security.IJwtFactory' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.AuthController'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BuildingController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BuildingController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BuildingService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.BuildingController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.CheckingAccountController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.CheckingAccountController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.CheckingAccountService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.CheckingAccountController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.PhoneNodeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.PhoneNodeController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.PhoneNodeService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.PhoneNodeController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType: Estato.Controllers.RoleController
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> Estato.Controllers.RoleController': Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Estato.Core.DAL.Entities.Role]'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.RoleController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.UserController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.UserController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.UserService' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.UserController'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ApplianceController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ApplianceController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ApplianceService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.ApplianceController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ArchitecturalStyleController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ArchitecturalStyleController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ArchitecturalStyleService' while attempting
> to activate 'Estato.Controllers.ArchitecturalStyleController'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BasementController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BasementController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BasementService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.BasementController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BuildActionController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BuildActionController': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BuildActionService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.BuildActionController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BuildTechnologyController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BuildTechnologyController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BuildTechnologyService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.BuildTechnologyController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BuildTypeService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeGroupController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeGroupController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.BuildTypeGroupService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.BuildTypeGroupController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ClientTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ClientTypeController': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ClientTypeService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.ClientTypeController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.CoolingTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.CoolingTypeController': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.CoolingTypeService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.CoolingTypeController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.CountryController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.CountryController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.CountryService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.CountryController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.DimensionController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.DimensionController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.DimensionService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.DimensionController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType: Estato.Controllers.DistrictController
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> Estato.Controllers.DistrictController': Unable to resolve service for
> type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.DistrictService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.DistrictController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ExteriorController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ExteriorController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ExteriorService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.ExteriorController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.FloorCoveringController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.FloorCoveringController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.FloorCoveringService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.FloorCoveringController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.HeatingFuelController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.HeatingFuelController': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.HeatingFuelService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.HeatingFuelController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.HeatingTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.HeatingTypeController': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.HeatingTypeService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.HeatingTypeController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.IndoorFeatureController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.IndoorFeatureController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.IndoorFeatureService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.IndoorFeatureController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.MetroKeyController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.MetroKeyController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.MetroKeyService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.MetroKeyController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.MoneyTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.MoneyTypeController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.MoneyTypeService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.MoneyTypeController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.OutdoorAmenityController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.OutdoorAmenityController':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.OutdoorAmenityService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.OutdoorAmenityController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.OwnerTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.OwnerTypeController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.OwnerTypeService'
> while attempting to activate
> 'Estato.Controllers.OwnerTypeController'.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType: Estato.Controllers.ParkingController
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> Estato.Controllers.ParkingController': Unable to resolve service for
> type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ParkingService' while attempting to
> activate 'Estato.Controllers.ParkingController'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.RegionController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.RegionController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.RegionService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.RegionController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.RoofTypeController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.RoofTypeController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.RoofTypeService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.RoofTypeController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.RoomController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.RoomController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.RoomService' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.RoomController'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.SizeNameController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.SizeNameController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.SizeNameService'
> while attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.SizeNameController'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ViewController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ViewController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ViewService' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.ViewController'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.ZoneController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.ZoneController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ZoneService' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.ZoneController'.)

Note, I already tried to add  builder.Services.AddScoped<Estato.Core.BLL.Services.ZoneService>();
also other services like ZoneService but I still have this error

Comment: What is `AddCustomizedMvc`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Guru Stron you can find it ServiceCollectionExtensions

Comment: try regist your services like :builder.Services.AddScoped<IZoneService,ZoneService>()

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a number of services that are not registered that your Controllers are dependent upon.

Taking the first error:

> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Estato.Controllers.AuthController Lifetime: Transient
> ImplementationType: Estato.Controllers.AuthController': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'Estato.Core.Security.IJwtFactory' while
> attempting to activate 'Estato.Controllers.AuthController'.)

I don't see IJwtFactory being registered anywhere.  You'll need to evaluate each exception in turn to ensure that all required services are registered.

Comment: Yeah, I added , but got same error

Comment: The 'same' error?  Or just another aggregate error, but without the IJwtFactory errors?  You'll need to re-read the aggregate error each time you fix one and knock them down one-by-one..

Comment: I found that I need to add "public IContainer ApplicationContainer {get; private set; } services.ConfigureAutofac(ApplicationContainer);" in program.cs as in startups.cs ConfigureServices, I'm working on it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this https://jinalkumarpatel.hashnode.dev/dependency-injection-in-net-with-autofac, thanks to all, here is part of my code to register services :

````
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<Autofac.ContainerBuilder>(autofacConfigure =>
{
 autofacConfigure
       .RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .As<DbContext>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    autofacConfigure
        .RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<>))
                    .As(typeof(BaseRepository<>))
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
...
}```
````